# Socket.getInputStream.read(...) throws SocketException on Android when server sends FIN packet

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to implement a client application for Android that connects to a server using `Socket`, exchanges some data, and then terminates the connection in a graceful way, as described in this article:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/articles/connection_release.html

However, the behavior of the client socket during disconnection does not behave as expected.

1. We have established a connection between Android client and server.
2. Client finishes sending all data and calls `socket.shutdownOutput()` (sends `FIN` to server).
3. Server receives the last bytes and calls its `socket.shutdownOutput()` (sends `FIN` to client).
4. Client reads the last bytes from the server and the last call to `socket.getInputStream().read(...)` throws the following exception:

   > `java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)` with cause: `android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)`

I expect the last call to `socket.getInputStream().read(...)` should return `-1`, which is the behavior I get when I run the same code on OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu.

Is there some setting of `Socket` which could fix the behavior on Android?

Comment: Are you sure `FIN` is being sent by the server?  `FIN` should not cause an `ECONNRESET` error.  Is the client connecting to the server via LAN/WiFi or cellular?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was trying it only in Android emulator, connecting to localhost machine (through 10.0.2.2 ip address). Maybe that is the cause?
I tried Wireshark and it is clearly visible that it is FIN and no RST.

Comment: It looks like this is only happening on Android emulator running on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. I tried it on Android emulator in Macos everything worked as expected - no exception was thrown.